# How to add class to teaser P?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8, how can I add a class to teaser p html tag. I want to style the paragraph in teaser only, not when whole content is shown.

Answer (score 4):

We can style that with simple css,

```
.node--view-mode-teaser .node__content p {
  /* write you style */
}
```

I think, you don't need to add separate class in P tag for that. and it would also affect only the teaser mode content :)

Comment: This answer is good, assuming he doesn't need to add a specific class name. Ex: [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) class names.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming you're talking about the default front page teasers**:

Edit the Frontpage view, and Instead of `Show: Teaser`, click on teaser and change it `Show: Fields`

Then you basically create your own custom teaser.

Add Fields: title, body (summary or trimmed), post date, comments link, etc...

[image]

Then **click on Style Settings** and the classes to your body (re-using pic from another answer)

[image]